# C++ Creating Lottery Guessing Program

Tags: c++

Okay so the project is to create a lottery number composed of 10 random positive integers and the user is suppose to guess it until the user guesses the correct number. All of my code looks good but when I run the program and enter in a number it gives me this MSVS Runtime Library error? I dont even know what it means as I am fairly new to programming. Help would be very appreciated!

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include "Lottery.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int size = 9; //declare variables
    int win[size];
    int g;
    srand(time(NULL));
    assign(win, size);
    draw(win, size);
    g = entry();
    if (check(win,size,g) == true) {
        cout << "Congradulations! You have won the lottery!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Try again!" << endl;
    }
    printOut(g);
}
```

Lottery.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "Lottery.h"

using namespace std;



int entry() {
    int guess;
    cout << "Enter a number from 0 to 99." << endl;
    cin >> guess;
    return guess;
}

void assign(int w[], int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        w[s] = -1;
    }
}

bool check(int w[], int s, int g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        if (g == w[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void draw(int w[], int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        int tmp = rand() % 100;
        if (check(w, s, tmp)) {
            i--;
        }
        else
            w[i] = tmp;
    }
}

void printOut(int g) {
    cout << "Numbers you have chosen:" << " " << g << endl;
}
```

Lottery.h

```
#ifndef LOTTERY_INCLUDED
#define LOTTERY_INCLUDED

void assign(int[], int);
bool check(int[], int, int);
void draw(int[], int);
int entry();
void printOut(int);

#endif //LOTTERY
```

Comment: On the less snide front, when Visual Studio stops the program it generally give you the option of breaking and using the debugger to see what happened. I strongly recommend doing this. Much more educational than being handed a canned answer.

Comment: Not trying to create error. Trying to solve one! Had a typo in title.

Comment: Off topic: recommend a call to `srand` near the top of `main` to seed the random number generator.

Comment: I don't have anything jumping out at me here. I'd have to run the code through a debugger, and you can do that just as easily as I can. Off topic: Read up on the Fisher-Yates shuffle as a better way to generate your array of random numbers. A C++ implementation easily portable to using an array in place of a `std::vector` can be found here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from a [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

Debugging tutorials are available elsewhere. But if something bad happens, don't panic and look for instructions.

First, your runtime error:

[image: your runtime error]

This has a link "Break and open exception settings" link or a "Break" button. Break which will take you to the end of main if you click it.

The details say we did something bad near `win`.

Look at this:

```
void assign(int w[], int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        w[s] = -1; //<------Oh oops!
    }
}
```

We know the length of the array is `s` i.e. 9, and are using `w[s]` where we clearly meant `w[i]`.
The extra details in the error are telling you a possible place to look.